# bash script ssh auto login

Tags: bash, ssh, autologin

Hello I am trying to make a script that when I run will connect and login to my ssh server.
However I'm not sure how to stop it asking for my password, I want to somehow incorporate my password into my script so I dont have to type it manually. So the end product is I just run script and its connected to my server.

At the moment I'm just using

#!/bin/bash 
ssh hank@192.168.1.9 -p 2222

Was wonder what I might add so I wouldn't have to type password each time? 
I was looked extensively for an answer but so far I my search has been fruitless. 
I would appreciate any help maybe a suggestion on a bash command I could look up and read about.

Comment: Extensively? You need to improve your Internet search skills. http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/152

Answer (score 3):

Create a public key and use it for authentication, e.g.:

http://www.howtoforge.com/set-up-ssh-with-public-key-authentication-debian-etch

Answer (score 1):

Use public key authentication, and probably run a ssh config file as well.

Simple summary on config files: http://nerderati.com/2011/03/simplify-your-life-with-an-ssh-config-file/